# Perl: Is there a limitation of string/regex?

Tags: regex, string, perl, if-statement

I have two patterns

```
$good = "/(Yo)| (Me)/";
$bad = "/(an)|(nd)/";

my $thestring: "You and Me";
```

Then I am allowing the String, if one or more of the good patterns fit and none of the bad ones:

```
if (($thestring =~ $good) && ($thestring !~ $bad))
{...
```

The String "You and Me" shouldn't be allowed, and it works for that example.

BUT by adding very much (~5000 chars) patterns to $good (e.g.(x1)|...|(xn)), the if statement allows sometimes that string.

I don't understand why? Are there somekind of limitations?

Edit:

In the original version I tried to identify names: 
By using the pattern "hari" the string is accepted and without it the string isn't accepted.  Normaly by seeing "und" the pattern should be disallowed...

```
my $text_to_search ="Bettina und Frank";                    #der zu pruefende Text ist jeweils ein Datensatz aus dem positiven datensatz
my $regexp_output_pos ="/(tr)|(ammi)|(hann)|(Per)|(ome)|(tel)|(ley)|(ro)|(Ya)|(ita)|(Zilv)|(Pat)|(Ale)|(llia)|(assi)|(Dell)|(ulee)|(Ur)|(ke)|(ansi)|(af)|(dh)|(leen)|(Nik)|(Anto)|(mun)|(Tild)|(vya)|(oko)|(mi)|(Emm)|(vel)|(nnon)|(olau)|(Yan)|(eld)|(land)|(tole)|(Len)|(ai)|(Sibe)|(na) /";#|(hari)/";
#my $regexp_output_neg ="/(und)|(01)|(at)|(20)/";

#my $regexp_output_pos ="/(ett)|(ran)/";
my $regexp_output_neg ="/(und)|(01)|(at)|(20)/";


if (($text_to_search =~ $regexp_output_pos) && ($text_to_search !~ $regexp_output_neg))
{
print "akzeptiert";

}
else
{
print "nicht akzeptiert"
}
```

Comment: Do you have the failing version so we can actually try it?

Comment: Do I understand this right: in exactly this provided example you change only `$good` so that is has a lot of alternations and then the `if` changes to true? No can't be, oh you say "sometimes"! Please provide a real example (or explain the problem in another better way). The problem can be only in `$bad` or `$thestring` if it enters the if, when it shouldn't.

Comment: That's right, By adding some string - for example "hari" it changes to positive.

Comment: Your `exclusion` pattern doesn't work the way you think it does. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your regex expect to match `"hari/"` while you wanted to match `"hari"` (and `"/tr"` instead of `"tr"`, `"/und"` instead of `"und"`, `"20/"` instead of `"20"`).

Also, it looks like you won't be using the captures, so drop them:

```
my $regexp_output_pos = qr/tr|ammi|hann|Per|Siebe|hari|na /; # shortened for clarity, "na" is special because a space after is expected
my $regexp_output_neg = qr/und|01|at|20/;
```

By the way, as you seem to be a beginner in Perl, don't expect perl to be wrong. perl has some bugs, but your own code probably has much more. The Perl features that you use here is basic stuff that has been tested for 20 years by thousands of other programmers.

Comment: why should I drop the capturing groups? I thought if I want to match "und" it has to be "(und)" doesn'T it?

Comment: so I have to write "qr" in front of the first "/"? And why is "na" special and needs to have a space after?

Comment: @Tyzak: No, it doen't. Capturing means you want to know which of the string has matched. You'll get the result in the `$1`, `$2`, `$3`... variables. But it will be hard to use that result in the way you wrote the regexp. Also if `$regexp_output_neg` matches its capture will overrides `$1`..`$4`so you can not reliably do something with the result. That's why I think that you are not using the captures.

Comment: @Tyzak: the space after "na" comes from your own code in the question. About `qr//`, see the [Perl documentation about quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: I got one more question, I want to add my patterns iterativ like $regexp_output_pos .= "" ... do I have to write "qr/" and "/" in the front of that, or do I have to use qr only if I write the whole regexp in one string?

Comment: @Tyzak: You can create the pattern as string `$s = $a.$b`, then turn it into a regex with `qr/$s/`. Or you can use the string as the pattern for the match directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(?!.*neg).*pos/s
```

will match strings that contain "pos" but do not contain "neg", so

```
my @pos = qw( tr ammi hann Per ome tel ley ro Ya ita Zilv
              Pat Ale llia ssi Del ulee Ur ke ansi af dh
              leen Nik Anto mun Tild vya oko mi Emm vel
              nnon olau Yan eld land tole Len ai Sibe na );
my @neg = qw( und 01 at 20 );

my $pos_pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @pos;
my $net_pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @neg;
/^(?!.*(?:$neg_pat)).*(?:$pos_pat)/s
```

But you could use your existing patterns if only you removed the extra "`/`" you added, or use qr instead.

```
my $pos_pat = "tr|ammi|hann|Per|ome|tel|ley|ro|Ya|ita|Zilv|"
            . "Pat|Ale|llia|assi|Dell|ulee|Ur|ke|ansi|af|dh|"
            . "leen|Nik|Anto|mun|Tild|vya|oko|mi|Emm|vel|"
            . "nnon|olau|Yan|eld|land|tole|Len|ai|Sibe|na ";
my $neg_pat = "und|01|at|20";
/^(?!.*(?:$neg_pat)).*(?:$pos_pat)/s
```

Comment: This regex will only detect the cases where the bad part is before the good part. "hann und" will match.

Comment: This is good stuff, but doesn't address one of the OP's significant issues, viz. the treatment of non-regex expressions on the RHS of the binding operator (`=~` / `!~`).

Comment: @dolmen, No, you are mistaken. Try it before contradicting someone.

Comment: @hochgurgler, What's on the RHS on the binding operator is ALWAYS a regex pattern. The problem is that it's not the desired regex pattern in the OP's case. While I didn't highlight the problem is his regex, I did show how to do it correctly and effectively. But there, just mentioned it.

Comment: @ikegami, What I was getting at was that if you put a string on the RHS of `=~` it is, as you say, treated as a regex pattern, but it is used as, literally, just a pattern, and not as a piece of Perl (as the OP might have been expecting), so if one puts say `/foo/` into the string, then it is not treated as a piece of perl `/foo/` (a.k.a. `m{foo}`) but rather `m{/foo/}`. (When using a string RHS, you are limited to matching only (as in `m//`), you can't do substitutions (`s///`) or translations (`tr///`).)

Comment: @hochgurgler, I well aware of that, and it is covered.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the RHS of an =~ or !~ is a string, then it will be treated as a match pattern, and to make the point, NOT an expression.

   So if you put slashes at either end of it, perl will actually look for those slashes in the search space.

   To put is another way, considering only this part of the code:

   ```
   my $regexp_output_neg ="/(und)|(01)|(at)|(20)/";

   if (... && ($text_to_search !~ $regexp_output_neg)) ...
   ```

   The `if` will work equivalently to

   ```
   if (... && ($text_to_search !~
       m/
             \/(und)
           | (01)
           | (at)
           | (20)\/
       /x
   )) ...
   ```

   So if `$text_to_search` happens to be '/und' or '01' or 'at' or '20/', i.e. the with the leading and trailing slashes incorporated into the first and last items respectively, then the regex will match, the `!~` will be false, the `if` expression will be false, and `if` will pass control to the `else` clause.

   But I don't think that is what you intended, so this latter part of the if condition will not work as you expect for the first and last values.
2. "BUT by adding very much (~5000 chars) patterns to $good (e.g.(x1)|...|(xn)), the if statement allows sometimes that string."

   Because of the explanation above, your "exclusion" pattern is probably not matching in the way you think it is. So by adding further things to the "inclusion" pattern, you eventually add something that matches your search space, and your `if` starts hitting its `then` clause.

Comment: That is not really precise, particularly, the pattern you wrote doesn't match `/und/`. It does match `/und` and `20/`, though.

Comment: omg^^ - okay, so everything except the two "/" "/" is okay? the !~ gives me a false, when the pattern occures in the string?

Comment: @Tyzak: The capture parentheses are also useless if you do nothing with $1, $2... See my own answer.

Comment: You should use `qr` to make regex objects and put them on the right hand side of `=~` and `!~`. (Read docs to find out more about `qr`.)